# UIScrollView starts out halfway down content

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I am trying to implement a UIScrollView in a similar fashion to the featured banner at the top of the App Store. I am adding 3 views and then paging through them using the code below. When the controller loads however, it is started with the content down a bit. If I tap on the view the content goes back into where it should be. How can I fix this? I've trying setting the content offset to 0, I've tried manually scrolling to the origin rect, and I've tried putting my views in a content view, but nothing has worked.

```
    featuredScrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
    featuredScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 3 * featuredScrollView.frame.size.width, height: featuredScrollView.frame.size.height)
    let contentView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 3 * featuredScrollView.frame.size.width, height: featuredScrollView.frame.size.height))
    featuredScrollView.addSubview(contentView)
    for i in 0..<3
    {
        let testView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(i) * featuredScrollView.bounds.size.width, y: 0, width: featuredScrollView.bounds.size.width, height: featuredScrollView.bounds.size.height))
        testView.backgroundColor = .blue
        testView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        testView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        contentView.addSubview(testView)
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: That did the trick! Respond with the answer and I'll mark it correct. Thanks!

Comment: It's not about question, but in this case UICollectionView is better that just UIScrollView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try set `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to `NO`?